# Responsive HTML5 Video Tag, multiple queries

Tags: javascript, html, video, responsive-design

I'm trying to use the media `attribute` in the `source` tag in some html5 `video`. Firefox loads each of the correct three sized videos on page load, but Chrome is loading the small video on all page widths.
*Scroll to the right in the code if you can't see the `media` attribute.*

The `video` tag uses `js` to choose the appropriate `poster` depending on page width. In case you're wondering what is going on there.

I use `CSS` to make the `video` tag fluid, but I'm trying to spare the large download for non-desktop users (based on page width).

I've seen a few things that the `media` attribute may not be supported and was wondering if that is why this fails in Chrome or if I'm doing it wrong. Or if I should try to just accomplish this using javascript and swap out the `src` attribute in the `source` tag.

If the `media` attribute isn't supported, can someone link me up, or even send a LetMeGoogleThatForYou link if you want to humble me.

```
<video poster="" data-posterlarge="poster.jpg" data-postermedium="poster-medium.jpg" data-postersmall="poster-small.jpg" controls>         
  <source type="video/webm;codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="video-small.webm" media="all and (max-width:480px)"></source>
  <source type="video/mp4;codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="video-small.mp4" media="all and (max-width:480px)"></source>
  <source type="video/webm;codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="video-medium.webm" media="all and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:800px)"></source>
  <source type="video/mp4;codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="video-medium.mp4" media="all and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:800px)"></source> 
  <source type="video/webm;codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="video.webm"></source>
  <source type="video/mp4;codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="video.mp4"></source>
  <small>THIS BROWSER DOES NOT HAVE NATIVE VIDEO SUPPORT</small>
</video>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content of you `source` tags are all identical, except for the sizes, the below code just combines and simplifies what is displayed.

If you need, I can make a jQuery version, but here's a pure-JS solution:

```
function size() {
 var width = window.innerWidth, size = '', source;
 if(width <= 480)
  size = '-small';
 else if(width > 480 && width <= 800)
  size = '-medium';
 source = '<source type="video/webm;codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="video' + size + '.webm" media="all and (max-width:480px)"></source><source type="video/mp4;codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="video' + size + '.mp4" media="all"></source><small>THIS BROWSER DOES NOT HAVE NATIVE VIDEO SUPPORT</small>';
 document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = source;
}
```

Then, remove all the code from the `video` tag, so all you have in the `body` is:

```
<video poster="" data-posterlarge="poster.jpg" data-postermedium="poster-medium.jpg" data-postersmall="poster-small.jpg" controls id="video"></video>
```

You'd call it onload by adding `onload="videoSize()"` to the `body` tag.  Due to my lack of knowledge on how-to use JSFiddle, I had to load it using their built-in system: http://jsfiddle.net/x8h5ebq6/2/

I added an `id` to the video tag, but you can leave that off if you swap `document.getElementById('video').innerHTML` for `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].innerHTML`, the `[0]` corresponding to the instance on the page of the `video` tag you want the script to target.  It can be seen at: http://jsfiddle.net/x8h5ebq6/1/

Comment: Right, this is a way to do it via `js`, but I was wondering if I even HAVE to based on the mixed and dated information I've seen about the `media` attribute.

Comment: I'm guessing you got the original reference code from http://css-tricks.com/video-source-by-screen-size/ and modified it.  Here's the problem, the `media` attribute isn't actually supported by any of the major browsers.  Even if some of them did, there are still others what won't.  Furthermore, using that method of a breakdown isn't supported by iOS.  Basically, if you want to ensure it'll work across browsers and platforms, your best option is use a script.  Even that page describes the issues of the `media` attribute and how JavaScript and work around it (they example a jQuery method).

Comment: Nice, good reference. I actually started my quest here: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/08/html5/responsive-html5-video but that article is dated and I was searching for more recent information. No iOs support is a deal breaker. `js` it is.

Comment: I am sorry to have to disappoint you, but somethings are simply not acceptable to some browser developers.  My reference is almost as old, but there are several additional sources to support that it is still held true.  I figured you might've used mine because of the file names being so similar, but coincidence happens. ^^'  I'm glad I was able to help. :)